# Last inserted id from generic repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My Generic repository class

```
 public class Repository<TEntity, TId> : IRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : class, IEntity<TId>
    {       
        protected readonly CBSContext _context;
        //private DbSet<TEntity> _entities;
      
        public Repository(CBSContext context)
        {
            _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
      //      _entities = _context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
    
         public async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity)
            {
               await Task.Run(() => _context.Add(entity));         
               return entity;
            }

}
```

Am using ef core 5 Rc.. After  insert id is not returning ? Any thing else need to be done..Thanks

EDIT:

After code change to not working..

```
   public async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity)
            {
               await _context.AddAsync(entity);         
               return entity;
            }
```

Comment: why are you doing this strange `Task.Run` instead of just `await _context.AddAsync`?

Comment: Not its not working

Comment: you cannot get id until _context.SaveChanges is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use _context.SaveChangesAsync() after Add(). Then you can get id.

Comment: Can show your UOW code for us to understand better.